# ssh-copy-id public key denied

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to copy my public ssh key to my vps, so I can log in with `ssh`.

However, when I enter the command:

```
ssh-copy-id me@myserver
```

I get this error message

```
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new    key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if   you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: see if you can log in manually and write to the file that it will be adding to, the authorized_keys file. ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  If you can then the ssh-copy-id should work. If not then see what stage gives a problem   The side you are logging into has to accept password login for you to get in. You can remove passwordlogin once ssh-copy-id has done its thing and enabled you to login via key.  PasswordAuthentication yes  (in sshd_config) file

Comment: thanks Jawa, that was indeed the solution. The issue I had, was that in the sshd_config file the PasswordAuthentication occured twice, and 'PasswordAuthentication yes' was overruled by 'PasswordAuthentication no'. I discovered this after three days of troubleshooting : )

Answer (score 4):

As Camilo already suggested, you can add the right SSH public key manually on the remote server.

In my case this same error occurred when the SSH program tried to use a different identity file than defined when using ssh-copy-id or couldn't just find the defined private key / identity file. You can observe what the SSH program does when executing the ssh command by adding -v to it:

```
ssh -v username@your-host-ip-or-domain
```

Then you just grab on your local machine any public key of which the SSH program tries out the private key, for example (on a Mac/Linux) the default key:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

... and add it to the remote's authorized_keys file in:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Another, in my case even better solution, was to add a custom host in my local ssh config file. On my Mac it is:

```
~/.ssh/config
```

Here you can add for example something like this:

```
Host mynewserver
        HostName some.IP.number.or.domain
        Port 20000 #if custom port is used and not the default 22
        User the_root
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_my_new_server
```

Then you just need to execute:

```
ssh mynewserver
```

...and Voilà

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the way that worked for me was to put it mannually, in this link you can find how to do it [Manually entry](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04). In this way i was able to connect via ssh even when using pair keys. When i was configuring it, the .ssh/authorized_keys file contain another key pointing to the initial machine, so i override that information with the contained in the /.ssh/id_rsa.pub of the initial machine

Comment: If you can Edit your answer with more details not just the link

Comment: I cannot cop&pasta from the local terminal to the remote terminal when copying the local `id_rsa.pub` - `ssh-copy-id` does not password authenticate at all!